# Zoom карты скроллом

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, svg, map, zoom

Доброго времени суток, делаю интерактивную карту, подскажите пожалуйста как увеличивать ее при скроле, нарезаю `svg`

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1821.3333 1138.6667">
   <path class="sector-1 area" d="m 510.39688,236.47144 24.88449,32.56162 67.50581,-17.47209 c -12.0776,-15.78552 -25.51801,-29.2997 -39.7093,-41.5624 z"></path>
   <path class="sector-2 area" d="m 561.48951,310.33074 66.71163,-14.29535 c -9.23214,-19.66037 -17.41297,-34.5899 -23.82558,-41.5624 l -66.4469,16.94263 c 8.19087,12.80308 16.70891,25.44257 23.56085,38.91512 z"></path>
   <path class="sector-3 area" d="m 578.69687,359.30554 78.88915,-16.14845 c -4.79821,-10.65119 -17.93537,-28.59897 -27.79651,-43.68023 l -66.18217,14.82481 z"></path>
   <path class="sector-4 area" d="M 590.87439,408.8098 699.67788,389.74934 662.35113,347.39275 578.9616,363.01174 Z"></path>
   <path class="sector-5 area" d="M 600.93408,450.63693 736.47516,426.2819 701.53098,393.72027 592.72749,414.10438 Z"></path>
  </svg>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#zoomSvg').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
    console.log(delta);
    return false;
});
```